# Setting up a local network with access to the internet through a wireless access point

Tags: switch, network, wireless, access-point

### Intro

At work we want to setup an 8 node raspberry pi cluster. The purpose of the cluster is to test different technologies and have a good time.

We cant manage the wifi at work and the only way we have access to the internet is through a Wireless Access Point.

We know it is possible to set up a local network, where the Raspberries can be accesed but without access to the whole wide web.

[EDIT]
The only way we can connect to the WWW is through wireless if the device is registered using the device mac-address.

### Question

Would we be able to set up some type of router that can take in Wifi from the Wifi Access Points and create a "local network" and that have access to WWW.

And would it be possible for users to:

1. Access the Raspberries when connected to the "local network"
2. Access the Raspberries when connected to the Wifi (Wireless Access Point)

## Image

The red square (?? Wifi router, router??) in the image below, is the missing link in our setup. The work network is located in the green zone and i bet they have alot of security and firewalls that we cant manage.

[image: Diagram of the network and how we think it could work]

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Comment: "_We cant manage the wifi at work and the only way we have access to the internet is through a Wireless Access Point._" Questions about networks you do not directly control are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to need is a WAP in client mode. You can connect that WAP to a switch and connect more nodes, bridging between the wireless network and the wired one - no real need for a router.

A router requires you to add a route to your new subnet on the upstream router, either statically or by using a routing protocol like OSPF. An alternative would be NAT, but you shouldn't NAT inside your own network.

If the network is not under your control you should talk to the admin first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, we can register a device using a mac address. The device can only be connected wirelessly.
Would it be possible to use a router with NAT and DHCP functionality and use that as a local network?

Comment: Many things are possible. If you add a router with NAT and your own DHCP server, you effectively hide that subnet from the rest of the network, so you should make sure that you comply to security policies.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a laptop connected to the WiFi Access Point then connect that laptop to the switch.

Switch by default will use your laptop as a gateway to the Internet. Thus all connected Raspberries will have access to the Internet.

In Windows you should share Internet connection for the connection of switch. Below screenshot shows how I did share connection through WiFi, but you should do it for wired connection for the switch.
[image]

Comment: Host configurations are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. Also, ICS sucks big time.

Comment: Unfortunately, host/server configurations are explicitly off-topic here.